# Find repeated character in a list

Tags: python

```
 my_list = [1,3,3,8,2,7,8]

 max = my_list[0]

 for i in range(1,len(my_list)):

    if my_list[i] > max:

       max = my_list[i]
print('Max number is :', max)
```

I wrote a code to find a max value in a list and it is working. Now I have to find its(I mean max values') number of repeated times. I have to change this code in order to find its max value and max values' repeated time. Example it will be 8 and 2.
But how to do it I do not know. I am stuck with it. Please help me with it.

Comment: See `list.count()` and its usage here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: what have you tried so far? do you know how to use dictionaries?

Comment: In addition, take a look at the `max()` function - it can save you a lot of code.

Comment: Your goal is maybe to create your `max` function but if it's not, you can just use `max(your_list)` to get it

Comment: Please don't shadow the `built-in`  `max`.

Comment: Did you see [How do I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2600191/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [1,3,3,8,2,7,8]

max = my_list[0]
count = 1

for i in range(1,len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i] > max:
        max = my_list[i]
        count = 1
    elif my_list[i] == max:
        count += 1
print('Max number is :', max)
print('Count :', count)
```

yields

```
Max number is : 8
Count : 2
```

---

Some coding style suggestions.

1. `max` is a built-in python function. It is considered to be a good idea to not override it. I suggest replacing it with `max_element` in the code.
2. There is a more pythonic way to iterate over lists by using `for element in list` syntax.

```
my_list = [1,3,3,8,2,7,8]

max_element = my_list[0]
count = 1

for v in my_list[1:]:
    if v > max_element:
        max_element = v
        count = 1
    elif v == max_element:
        count += 1
print('Max number is :', max_element)
print('Count :', count)
```

Comment: Let's don't shadow the Python `built-in` `max`, shall we?